# Question regarding synthesist summoner and No Breath

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, summoner, eidolon

So the Eidolon can take an evolution called No Breath. What if the summoner already has a similar ability, where they don't breathe and can't be affected by anything that needs to be inhaled? When fused, could they then be poisoned? Would they need to breathe when fused even though their real body doesn't need to? Could the fused summoner/eidolon suffocate or drown when the summoner can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) has no *separate* eidolon to harm

If the summoner possessing the archetype [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) is immune to an effect, he's also immune to that effect while his eidolon is present. When synthesist and summoner are fused, there's no distinction between summoner and eidolon. The two are one creature. Among other effects, this means that

> …[t]he synthesist gains the eidolon’s hit points as temporary hit points. When these hit points reach 0, the eidolon is killed and sent back to its home plane.… The synthesist also gains access to the eidolon’s special abilities and the eidolon’s evolutions.… Neither the synthesist nor his eidolon can be targeted separately, as they are fused into one creature. The synthesist and eidolon cannot take separate actions. While fused with his eidolon, the synthesist can use all of his own abilities and gear, except for his armor.…

Typically, the only things that affect the fused eidolon exclusively instead of the synthesist–eidolon fusion creature are effects that are like the spells *banishment* and *dismissal*. The rest of the time it's just synthesist, synthesist, synthesist, not, as is normally the case, summoner and eidolon as separate beings.

A synthesist isn't the invincible Iron Man nor the incredible Hulk, but a uniquely weird fantasy creation. A sythesist activates his eidolon, changes his appearance, and gains a suite of special abilities. When the temporary hp are depleted, the creature's appearance returns to normal, and it loses that suite of special abilities.

While fused with his eidolon, an assassin could no more poison a synthesist's eidolon separately than the assassin could opt to poison just a victim's skin or liver. Likewise, While fused with his eidolon, a synthesist can drown, but the fused eidolon can't also or separately drown—they aren't a *they* but one being.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to ask about this was because the Eidolon is the summoner's physical form, the summoner takes on its physical ability scores and "speaks with its voice" which I am taking literally as the character I am playing is functionally senseless (don't ask) but has the benefit of not needing to eat, drink, or breathe. Generally things like this take the "round down" approach. I will have to see if the others have any objections to this reading of the rules.

Comment: @KenjiShiratsuki If I can be bold for a moment, you're overreading the ability fuse eidolon. While it can be skinned in a variety of ways, the fused eidolon *isn't* the summoner's physical form—that'd be the Hulk with Banner's brain. Instead, the synthesist takes on the abilities of his eidolon. It's closer to if Banner were to Hulk up and, when he did, instead of replacing his character, Hulk parts spontaneously appeared on Banner and damage eventually causes that Hulkness to disappear.

Comment: I see. So assume for a moment that this is Daredevil and not Hulk. Daredevil uses this ability to fuse with his Eidolon; would he then gain the ability to see? Daredevil is naturally blind, but the book mentions using the Eidolon's senses.

Comment: @KenjiShiratsuki I don't think fusing with an eidolon should cure blindness, even temporarily, but you can ask your GM. When the ability fuse eidolon says that "the synthesist perceives through the eidolon’s senses,"  I suspect most GMs will rule that the synthesist himself still can't perceive using senses that are impaired. Binoculars don't let a blind man see.

Comment: @JKimball That's… a really good point, actually. Carefully dodging, I think—since senses are unmentioned by this question (which I think, honestly, is sufficiently answered)—that this line of inquiry is better confined to its own question. Feel free to pose it!

Comment: @HeyICanChan What about a non-synthesist and a blind summoner, using bonded senses - "share the senses of his eidolon, hearing, seeing, smelling, tasting, and touching everything the eidolon does".

Is that diferent than a synthesist  who "perceives through the eidolon’s senses"?

Comment: @JKimball Like I said, I think this line of inquiry is better suited to its own question. It's beyond the scope of this question, and, as per the Kenji's comment, it's kind of important to the PC. I should've recommended a senses question be posed separately originally, and it's totally my bad for deigning to do so in comments in the first place. *Mea culpa.*